# Help in GRASS/QGIS/Python

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, grass-gis

I have Idea about ArcGIS, and a bit of QGIS and zero programming knowledge, which I am trying for thesedays. I saw GRASS GIS and have started working with shapefiles, which are not being loaded... :( I saw the toolbox and could not find v.in.shape tool. Using file management -> import vector into grass-> v.in.ogr.qgis I cod load the file but could not go farther. I now wanted to access this via python console. Any guide on how should I carry on with my task through which I may be able to use the tools. I can get good help in programming. I tried to get my shapefile read in python console in QGIS but could not.
I am very basic in this so please give easy solutions.

thanks a lot.

Comment: You better give your title a bit more focus. But If you want to use python in QGIS this is the place you are looking for: [http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/intro.html](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/intro.html)

Comment: since all these are being worked as a single package I found this appropriate. thx for your help anyways... :)

Comment: @AlexandreNeto I am following the same steps of the manual but the shapefile is not loading... my path and the qgis prefix path are correct.

Comment: You need to be more explicit, does it give you any error? Or you simply don't see it on the canvas?

Comment: Are you doing the layer registry? Check the last part of this [http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/loadlayer.html#map-layer-registry](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/loadlayer.html#map-layer-registry)

Comment: adding this to registry was good... though that is to render the map to open layers, i dint use it previously... :) thx again... :)

Comment: very very basic but I am not getting what is this "fid" @AlexandreNeto I actually want to change the geometry from lie to polygon, or u can say to polygonize it... using this command. layer.changeGeometry(fid, geometry)

Comment: I think that is a totally different question. You should post a new question for that. Very short answer, fid is the feature ID.

Comment: thx a lot... i get that,,, :)